# Loop through directory and create data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a data frame and then loop through a directory filled with csv files and add those to the data frame. I'm trying to use the following code:

```
df = []
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    for fname in fileList:
         df = pd.read_csv(fname)
```

Unfortunately I'm getting an error stating that "File CIN_2017 does not exist" (it does). Any insight into how to add all these csv files into a dataframe? There is a .DS_Store in there but everything else is just a csv. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try another solution with `glob` for return file names, then loop in list comprehension and create `list of DataFrames`. last concate them to one big df:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('files/*.csv')
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(fp) for fp in files], ignore_index=True)
```

It is same as:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('files/*.csv')
dfs = []
for fp in files:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(fp))

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

un_process_file = []

master_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns=['item_sku', 'external_product_id', 'standard_price', 'quantity'])
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for file_path in files:
        if file_path.endswith('.csv'):
            try:
                print file_path
                file_name = os.path.join(root, file_path)
                file_frames = pd.read_csv(file_name, skiprows=2,
                                          usecols=['item_sku', 'external_product_id', 'standard_price', 'quantity'])
                master_frame = master_frame.append(file_frames)
            except:
                un_process_file.append(file_path)
master_frame = master_frame.rename(
    columns={'item_sku': 'sku', 'external_product_id': 'asin', 'standard_price': 'price'})
master_frame = master_frame.drop_duplicates(subset='asin')
master_frame.to_csv('masterfile.txt', sep='\t')
if un_process_file:
    print '\nUnable To Process these files\n'
    for files in un_process_file:
        print files
```

I have a similar problem. I made this solution. Modify `columns` name according to you need